# Use DynamicResource to fill Color

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, dynamicresource

I'd like to do something like this in my xaml `ResourceDictionary`:

```
 <Color x:Key="ForegroundTextColor" > {DynamicResource {x:Static vs_shell:EnvironmentColors.ToolWindowTextBrushKey}} </Color>
```

But Color accept as value only stuff like #xxxxx.

Any idea to reach my goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Color are not dynamic but you can use a SolidColorBrush, not really a color but something who accepts Color and allows you to use to fill in Rectangle, Background,...

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor" Color="{DynamicResource MyDynamicResource}" />
```

Comment: Can I use the solidcolorbrush in Text, Border etc etc?

Comment: Sure :)  example: <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource MyColor}" Text="hello" />

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working at all: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundTextColor" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static vs_shell:EnvironmentColors.ToolWindowTextBrushKey}}"></SolidColorBrush>
I receive the error: The resource ... cannot be resolved :(

Comment: The problem is with your x:Static vs_shell:... value not with the dynamic one. Your value is static by name so I don't understand what you try to do :/

Comment: I'm simply trying to catch the color from the current theme set for visual studio (I'm developing an isolated shell)

Comment: and this color is static, if you change the color theme, you will need to restart tout shell. You can't have a dynamic "link" on it :(